# Unit Testing a Factory with a Generator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I have a `Factory` class that uses a `Generator` class (there will be several of these, each with a different algorithm) to produce arrays of objects. I am trying to program this with a TDD approach, but I'm having great difficulty with deciding on tests. I've barely just started with TDD, so I guess that my tests are, in fact, ugly abominations.

These are the tests I have on the `Factory`:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MapRegionFactoryTests
{
    [Test,
     Description("Tests if a MapRegion is successfully created.")]
    public void TestBasicRegionCreation()
    {
        var mapRegionFactory = new MapRegionFactory();
        MapRegion mapRegion = mapRegionFactory.GenerateMapRegion();

        Assert.IsTrue(mapRegion != null);
    }

    [Test,
     Description("Tests if a MapRegionFactory's RegionSizeX, RegionSizeY and RegionSizeZ are properly initialized" +
                 "to their default values.")]
    public void TestDefaultPropertyInitialization()
    {
        var mapRegionFactory = new MapRegionFactory();

        Assert.Greater(mapRegionFactory.RegionSizeX, 0);
        Assert.Greater(mapRegionFactory.RegionSizeY, 0);
        Assert.Greater(mapRegionFactory.RegionSizeZ, 0);
    }

    [Test,
     Description("Tests if properties can only be assigned numbers above zero.")]
    public void TestGreaterThanZeroPropetyAssignment()
    {
        var mapRegionFactory = new MapRegionFactory
                               {
                                   RegionSizeX = -8,
                                   RegionSizeY = -3,
                                   RegionSizeZ = 0
                               };

        Assert.Greater(mapRegionFactory.RegionSizeX, 0);
        Assert.Greater(mapRegionFactory.RegionSizeY, 0);
        Assert.Greater(mapRegionFactory.RegionSizeZ, 0);
    }

    [Test,
    Description("Tests if the default RegionFactory can deliver a region filled with tiles.")]
    public void TestRegionCount()
    {
        // Test the count of objects again?
    }
}
```

And a single test for the `Generator`:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MapRegionGeneratorTests
{
    [Test,
     Description("Tests that a region of a certain size is properly filled with Block objects.")]
    public void TestDefaultRegionSize()
    {
        const int regionSize = 16;

        var mapRegionGenerator = new MapRegionGenerator();

        var regionData = mapRegionGenerator.GenerateRegion(regionSize);

        foreach (Block element in regionData)
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I approaching this correctly so far? I know that `MapRegionFactory` will have an `IMapRegionGenerator` injected through Castle.Windsor, but how do I mock something as complex as a generator? I can't replicate the whole generating code, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about your code to know exactly how this test should look, but it ought to give you a basic idea of how to test the factory with a mock generator.

```
[Test]
public void RegionFactoryDelegatesToRegionGenerator()
{
    var mockGenerator = new Mock<IMapRegiongenerator>();
    var factory = new MapRegionFactory(mockGenerator.Object);

    var expectedRegion = new Region();
    var regionSize = CreateRandomRegionSize();
    mockGenerator.Setup(g=>g.GenerateRegion(regionSize)).Returns(expectedRegion);

    factory.SetRegionSize(regionSize);
    Assert.That(factory.GetRegion(), Is.SameAs(expectedRegion));
}
```

> how do I mock something as complex as a generator? I can't replicate
>   the whole generating code, no?

For the purpose of testing the factory, you just have to ensure that it uses the generator correctly, whatever correctly means.  Your tests, like your production code for the factory, don't and should not care how a generator works, just that it fulfills its contract and returns a Region.

Comment: The last sentence is what I've been looking for. I didn't know if it was necessary to replicate the generating code or just test how the factory uses the generator.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use **constructor injection**, i.e. pass an instance of `IMapRegionGenerator` type to the constructor of `MapRegionFactory` class?

```
class MapRegionFactory
{
    public MapRegionFactory(IMapRegionGenerator generator)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

After this you can create mock for the `IMapRegionGenerator` type and pass it for testing.

Comment: That's precisely what I will do - there isn't any issue with that. What I do have an issue with is how to actually mock and unit test the generator. Do I just copy-paste the generating code? Or do I return some array of random objects?

Comment: @PavelMatuska, could you please add the definition of `IMapRegionGenerator` interface to the question?

Comment: The other answer was spot on, but thanks for the effort. I've one-upped both answers.